# How to get the related model class name from a ManyToOneRel object?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a class structure like the following:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    some_fields = ...

    def get_related_child_file_models_info(self):
    """
    This return a generator containing all the related file model
    info for each child
    """
        links = (
            [f.name, f]
            for f in self._meta.get_fields()
            if (f.one_to_many or f.one_to_one)
            and f.auto_created
            and not f.concrete
            and "files" in f.name
        )   
        return links

class ChildFileA(models.Model):
    ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="child_a_files"
    )
    file = models.FileField()
    ...

class ChildFileB(models.Model):
    ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="child_b_files"
    )
    file = models.FileField()
    ...
```

If I use this generator inside a for loops I get

```
['child_a_files', <ManyToOneRel: app_name.childfilea>]
```

and

```
['child_b_files', <ManyToOneRel: app_name.childfileb>]
```

The goal is to handle a complex files upload process where I have around 30 different models to store some files for each parents.

And I try to avoid having to manually create the code for each.

**How to get the class name** `ChildFileA` **and** `ChildFileB` **from the** `ManyToOneRel` **object?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access these with `.field.model`. For example:

```
def get_related_child_file_models_info(self):
    return [
        (f.name, f.field.model)
        for f in self._meta.get_fields()
        if (f.one_to_many or f.one_to_one)
        and f.auto_created and not f.concrete
        and "files" in f.name
    ]
```

This will return a *reference* to the class of that model. So here it will refer to `ChildFileA` and `ChildFileB`. You can access the `.__name__` attribute of that class to obtain the class name, like:

```
def get_related_child_file_models_info(self):
    return [
        (f.name, f.field.model.__name__)
        for f in self._meta.get_fields()
        if (f.one_to_many or f.one_to_one)
        and f.auto_created and not f.concrete
        and "files" in f.name
    ]
```

Comment: You rock!   Can you replace by `f.field.model.__name__` so we have the perfect answer!